# rticles PLOS template appears broken

Tags: templates, latex, r-markdown, rticles

A fresh install of R, RStudio, `tinytex` and `rticles` returns the following error when trying to compile the PLOS template from the `rticles` package (under R markdown, from template):

```
! Argument of Â has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.275 \section{Introduction}\label{introduction}}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Untitled.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Untitled.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Inspecting the TeX file shows this on lines 274-275:

```
\hypertarget{introduction}{%
\section{Introduction}\label{introduction}}
```

It looks like it ignores the previous line and considers the bracket on l.275 to be superfluous, but I'm not savvy enough in LaTeX to figure out a fix. Is the template broken, or is there some solution for this?

I've tried this on multiple machines with the same result.

Comment: Can you share the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Sure, does this work? https://pastebin.com/0BvZ1vgf

Comment: Ah, the problem is the `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`, better use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (which is actually the default, so not necessary to load)

Comment: Wow, impressive! Thank you! I managed to fix it by making the change you suggested in the template stored in ...\R\win-library\4.1\rticles\rmarkdown\templates\plos\resources

Comment: You're welcome! (found a recent duplicate instead :) )

Comment: (if possible, try to report this to the maintainer of the template you use)